# Two different routes simultaneously on one method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a controller with a method

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpGet("books/{bookId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks(string bookId)
        {
           ///  bookId is null here for api/v1/Books?bookId={Guid}
        }
}
```

Two routes `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpGet("books/{bookId}")]` worked fine on .Net Core 2.1 vesrion, but with upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 calling the route `[HttpGet]` stopped getting `bookId` from query string, it seems that it tries to take it from route by default.

When I try to set a `[FromQuery]` attribute for `bookId` parameter, the second route `books/{bookId}` stops taking `bookId` from route, so it is null.

As I suppose, upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 needs some changes to Startup controller routing, but I do not see this case would be described in migration guide.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I have seen the `[Route]` attribute used for defining the route. If you want to get the value from the query, then you should denote that with another attribute:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("books")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksWithOptionalId([FromQuery] string bookId)
    {
       /// both these will call this method (the second one will have a null bookId)
       ///  api/v1/Books?bookId={Guid}
       ///  api/v1/Books
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("books/{bookId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksById(string bookId)
    {
       /// ONLY this uri will work for this method (bookId is guaranteed to not be null)
       ///  api/v1/Books/{Guid}
    }
```

These are two *very* different methods. `bookId` isn't required in the first method, while in the second method it *is* required.